# Not able to display the data using routes

Tags: angular

I have created a route for the dashboard page but it is not displaying any data on the page and there is no error.

here is my code:

app.component.html

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button mat-button routerLink='/dashboard'>Dashboard</button>        
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
```

dashboard.component.html

```
  <p style="margin-top: 50px;">dashboard works!kcjbacbaicbaicbaibcaidcbi</p>
```

app.module.ts

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
  import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
  import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
  import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'; 
  import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
  import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip'; 
  import { MatIconModule, MatListModule, MatInputModule } from  '@angular/material';

 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
 import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
 import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component';

  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  NavbarComponent,
  SidebarComponent,
  DashboardComponent
 ],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 NgbModule,
 BrowserAnimationsModule,
 MatButtonModule,
 MatMenuModule,
 MatTooltipModule,
 MatIconModule,
 RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent}

 ])
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dasboard.component.html

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
     selector: 'dashboard',
     templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
    })
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor() { }

        ngOnInit() {
        }
    }
```

How can I display the data?, I have tried in a multiple ways like putting the data inside the div tag but still, I am not able to see the data and moreover I am not seeing any data.

right now I am using angular 8

Comment: you are missing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Have you configured routing in your project?

Comment: is there any error showing in browser console?